# Корректное положение курсора при фокусе редактируемого дива

Tags: javascript, html, css, вёрстка, wysiwyg

Имеется у меня вот такая страничка, с редактируемым `div` и нередактируемым `span` внутри. При клике на див (в конец строки) курсор становится некорректно, как это можно поправить?

```css
.tag {
  background-color: #2475ff;
  border-radius: 2px;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 600;
  height: 18px;
  line-height: 16px;
  margin: 3px 0 5px;
  padding: 1px 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.content {
  border: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
  border-radius: 2px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: block;
  font-family: "Open Sans", "Arial", sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 24px;
  min-height: 30px;
  outline: medium none;
  padding: 0 8px;
  transition: border 0.2s ease 0s;
  width: 100%;
}
.content:focus {
  border-color: #007c99;
}
```

```html
<div class="content" contenteditable="true">
1111
<span contenteditable="false" class="tag">#tag</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Выход найден. Обернуть span в span с пробелом и прописать отрицательные боковые отступы, что бы курсор становился вплотную с контейнером тега.

```css
.tag_container {
  margin: 0px -5px;
}    
.tag {
  background-color: #2475ff;
  border-radius: 2px;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 600;
  height: 18px;
  line-height: 16px;
  margin: 3px 0 5px;
  padding: 1px 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.content {
  border: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
  border-radius: 2px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: block;
  font-family: "Open Sans", "Arial", sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 24px;
  min-height: 30px;
  outline: medium none;
  padding: 0 8px;
  transition: border 0.2s ease 0s;
  width: 100%;
}
.content:focus {
  border-color: #007c99;
}
```

```html
<div class="content" contenteditable="true">
    1111
    <span contenteditable="false" class="tag_container">
        &nbsp;
        <span contenteditable="false" class="tag">#tag</span>
        &nbsp;
    </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Способ 1.** Если закрыть теги так:

```
</span></div>
```

то курсор внутри спана показываться не будет. Однако, похоже, он вообще не будет показываться в последней позиции. По крайней мере, в хроме.

**Способ 2.** Добавить после спана ещё символ, например, неразрывный пробел:

```
</span>&nbsp;
```

Comment: К сожалению если динамически вставлять span, пробел не помогает. Он обрезается автоматически, как я понял ...

Comment: попробовал даже <span> </span> - не помогло